# How do you save table with foreign key relation using Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am using entity framework 5.0 and I am not able to save tables with foreign key relation. I have a table called "Order" (OrderID & Date) and a table called "OrderLine" (Price,ID,OrderID). With the Following code, I am unable to save OrderLine. System just saves data in Order table.

```
  using (var db = new DartProjectionsDb())
            {
                var view = new Order
                {
                    OrderID = e.Identity.Identifier,
                    Date = SystemTime.UtcNow(),

                };

                     OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();

                     orderLine.ID = 1;
                     orderLine.OrderID = e.Identity.Identifier;
                     orderLine.Price = 100;


                     view.OrderLines.Add(orderLine);

                db.Orders.Add(view);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Could you show the edmx diagram? is the a relation between the tables?
EF sometimes "hide" many-to-many tables

Comment: @Jens kloster: Order and OrderLine is having one to Many relation

Answer (score 0):

try add the orderline to the db like this:

```
db.OrderLines.Add(orderline)
```

but I would have expected EF to do that behind the scenes.

Comment: I am getting following error:   Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: ok, and that does `EntityValidationErrors` say? what is the error(s)? It's not a property im familiar with

Comment: It says : {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult} Thats it :(

Comment: Can you please share a link or sample code which will help me add tables with foreign key relations

Comment: sry, i don't have a link. Perhaps (im taking a wild guess) the Id value (of either Order og OrderLines) is a dublicate? The `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult`is just the type name, i bet it can be expanded some more. I would start by trying that